# Mypy: using TypedDict as both kwargs for __init__ and as annotations for the class itself

Tags: python, type-hinting, mypy, python-typing

I am trying to have a class with dynamic properties that are pre-written inside a TypedDict, that is then passed as kwargs. Perhaps this is impossible to properly type with mypy, however I was thinking that I might be following the wrong approach.
This is my attempt so far:

```
from typing import NotRequired, TypedDict, Unpack

class KwargsDict(TypedDict):
    integer: int
    string: NotRequired[str]


class DynamicDataClass:
    def __init__(self, **kwargs: Unpack[KwargsDict]):
        for key, value in kwargs.items():
            setattr(self, key, value)


klass1 = DynamicDataClass(integer=1, string="2")
klass1.integer   
klass2.string    

klass2 = DynamicDataClass(integer=1)
klass2.integer   
klass2.string
```

In the above example, Mypy returns `"DynamicDataClass" has no attribute "integer"` and so forth for all the dynamic properties of the DynamicDataClass instances.

Is there some better and compliant way to tell mypy that DynamicDataClass inherits annotations from KwargsDict, and all the attributes typed in KwargsDict are also present in DynamicDataClass?

I was thinking that perhaps Generics could help, but I have no idea how to assign a generic typeddict to the class's annotations.

Comment: I don’t think this is possible, mainly because `TypedDict` is a highly special typing construct wearing the skin of a normal-looking class. I would opt for dynamic stub generation for what you’re looking for; the `ast` module is very powerful.